# Removing Delta 4 Inch Faucet

Tags: faucet

I believe this is an older Delta faucet. I have removed the two plastic nuts for the left and right handle , but I can’t reach the nut that’s holding the spout in space. I have also tried removing the handles using hex keys.

Here’s the view from the bottom, it’s very difficult to reach the middle nut because of the bar connecting the left and right handle together

[image]

Here is the view from the top

[image]

Comment: Try removing the chrome valve covers.  There might be  larger nut under there that is holding the valves in place.

Comment: I believe I need hex keys to unscrew the handles and pop them off. Should I start here ?

Comment: The picture's not that clear but if you see a hex screw in there, go with trying to loosen it.

Comment: Can you post a bigger/more close up photo of the bottoms of the valves and spout?

Comment: Do you have a larger/closer picture?

Comment: What kind of tool(s) are you using?  Do you have a basin wrench?